# Hide PyCharm "uncommitted changes" indicators

Tags: git, pycharm

How can I hide the indicators that PyCharm shows in the left and right gutters showing what uncommitted changes I have (in Git)?

example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXEHF.png

Answer (score 1):

`Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General` has two fields that may be of interest: `Added Lines` and `Modified Lines`. Unchecking `Background` should do what you want.

Please note that you will have to create/use a custom Scheme to make those changes and save them.